# HP ALM / QC 12 development questions

Tags: vb.net, hp-quality-center, alm

I'm currently using the QC11 defects module and have a ton of visual basic scripts that I've built. Soon we'll be moving to QC12, and although I have seen that QC12 is based on 'new' technology, I can't find any specific details on what this.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to migrate my visual basic scripts to QC12 ?

What language will I have to re-write them in ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

QC isn't quite based on a new technology, rather QC has a new html based client which run in any modern browser.

This new client does not run vbscript workflow, instead it provides a new model for extending project customization.

In the new client you can define buiseness rules in a wizard like ui, rules which be applied during entity modification.